# Lock the button in the flutter by double pressing

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form that is filled out, and then it is sent to the database by the button (by post method). But there was a problem with the form data being sent for about 2 seconds. And the "Submit Form" button can be clicked several times during this time. Is it possible to somehow make so that after the first press of the button this button is blocked ??
Code where the button in the widget is used:

```html
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: 10.0,
                height: 40.0,
                child: RaisedButton.icon(
                  label: Text(
                    "Submit Form",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send_to_mobile),
                  onPressed: makeRequest ,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
            ),
```

Form of sending data by post method:

```html
  Future<void> makeRequest() async {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback =
    ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

    String url = global.urlVar + "/forms";

    Map map = {
      "seals": _mySeals,
      "data_area": global.dataArea,
      "object": global.nameObj,
      "type": global.typesOp,
      "user": global.nameUser,

    };

    HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');

    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

    if (200 == response.statusCode) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Status()));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Error_Auth()),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isFetching = false;

Future<void> makeRequest() async {
    if(!isFetching){
setState(() {
   isFetching = true;
});
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback =
    ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

    String url = global.urlVar + "/forms";

    Map map = {
      "seals": _mySeals,
      "data_area": global.dataArea,
      "object": global.nameObj,
      "type": global.typesOp,
      "user": global.nameUser,

    };

    HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');

    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

    if (200 == response.statusCode) {
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Status()));
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Error_Auth()),
      );
    }
setState((){ 
isFetching=false;
});
 } 
  }
```

in case you are using stateful widget;

PS. also there is enabled option argument in raised button so you can let user know that button is disabled

```
RaisedButton.icon(
                  label: Text(
                    "Submit Form",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
enabled: !isFetching
//disableColor: Colors.grey there several option for theming if disabled
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send_to_mobile),
                  onPressed: makeRequest ,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I changed the first part (sending form), and all without errors. But in the part where the button is displayed there was a problem. (The named parameter 'enabled' isn't defined.)

Comment: in this part "enabled: !isFetching"

Comment: Another way to disable is ‘onPressed : isFetching? null : makeRequest;’